# Access to #LinkedIn Contacts API and Connections API

Tags: linkedin-api

**How exactly can I get access to #LinkedIn Contacts API and Connections API?** I would appreciate a list of steps, and probability of success. I have asked LinkedIn help about this and they told me to use StackOverflow. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

These APIs are private. Nobody can guarantee that you will get access to them, and if you don't have a good reason to have access to them, you almost definitely will not get access.

That being said, there are ways to apply for access. Notably, setting up a [business page](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/710/create-a-linkedin-page?lang=en) and [creating an app](https://developer.linkedin.com/) will get you access to non-restricted APIs.

To get access to Contacts and Connections specifically (which are both restricted APIs), you will have to [apply](https://developer.linkedin.com/content/developer/global/en_us/index/partner-programs/apply) for access. Once again, in terms of guaranteeing your application's acceptance, it is impossible to say whether or not (for certain) you will or will not get in.

*There is no set of steps that will guarantee access.*

Comment: Thank you. To which program should I apply to try to get access to those APIs?  
    Talent Solutions Partnership Request Form,
    Marketing Developer Program,
    Sales Navigator Application Platform,
    LinkedIn Learning Integration Partner Program ?

Comment: I have the same question as @Yar. I don't see where the Contacts API would fall under for those programs